# can I only have one runnable for this android that will allow postdelay to work only on a method?

Tags: java, android

This code is inside of a method and that method runs onStart for an android application. what this does is that it presses a button for 3 seconds which changes its color from blue to red and then goes back to its orginal state; then the next button does the same thing. This process is repeated for three different buttons. The code below works perfectly fine but is there a way to put all this code into one runabble object? I tried but a have problems with the .postDelayed because it would just press all the buttons at the same time instead of each button turn off and on at the given time.

The reason why I want this is because I created a random generator class that builds random patterns for Buttons class on android and I put that in a 2d array called list which is of type Button. however when I put something like list[x][y] and int x and int y are outside of r or r1 which are Runnable I get an error that says that only static variables can go inside of this new object. Is there any way I can use these variables so I can make a for loop or while loop to make something like list[x][y] instead of hardcore list[0][0] like how it is right now. Please help!!!

```
    handler = new Handler();
      r = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            list[0][0].setPressed(false);

        }


    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 3000);

    r1 = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            list[0][1].setPressed(true);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r1, 3000);

    r2 = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            list[0][1].setPressed(false);
            list[0][2].setPressed(true);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r2, 6000);

    r3 = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            list[0][2].setPressed(false);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r3, 9000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make correction with run method of runnable and make it generic method for all the buttons.

You can replace logic for the code

```
list[0][0].setPressed(false);
```

and use something like, In place of doing list[0][0] just take the common view (button) variable and initialize it with clicked button so your runnable will take action as per the view click and in this case you don't need to have 3 different runnable different for each button.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? For my application I want the user to repeat the pattern that is shown to them when the application starts. And if they get it right then they go to the next question which has a different pattern created by the random generator. At start all the buttons are assumed to be not pressed or that ,setPressed is false.

Comment: Sorry if my comment sounds dumb. But I am new to android programming and really don't know to much on threads either. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can apply logic what evenr you want in runnable run method that is generic to all buttons. As i suggested keep your runnable generic and apply logic within that only.